# Does hook_node_info() have to be in .module or can it be in .install?

Tags: 7, installation, nodes

due to some code sharing it would help me quite a bit if I could put hook_node_info() to a .install file instead of a .module file. Now, from what I've tested it doesn't seem that it could be a problem but then every tutorial says you have to put it in .module file.

And the official documentation is silent in regards to this problem. So my question is, can I do it without braking something?

Answer (score 0):

`hook_node_info` should be in the .module file. However, you could implement the hook in the module file and then just call `module_load_install` from there to include another function in the .install file, if that helps. Another option is to export the content type using a module such as Features instead.

Comment: Should be as "everyone says it should be" or as "there's a reason it should be there"? Considering other options: I know about them but I have a very specific situation where I can't really use them (I want to have my custom type definition in separate file (there's a func that returns it) but I need it in .install (and 'case this hook) in .module as well. The problem is I can't include it to both because it causes PHP redefinition errors (I know I can simply duplicate the code but...)

Considering features I know about them but it's too big of a canon for me.

Comment: The install file isn't loaded by default when hooks are invoked. However, you can call any custom function from `hook_node_info` no need to declare the same function twice.

Comment: Of course some hooks are ok in .install but not `hook_node_info` For more info see [`_node_types_build`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/_node_types_build/7)

Comment: Will look into that. Considering the custom function... that's the problem. I have a custom function and I have it in a 3rd file. But I need it (its output) in both .install and (thanks to the hook) .module

The problem is: 1) can't include the 3rd file to both -> PHP error; 2) can't include it to .module only as .install is loaded first and would throw function not implemented error 3) can't include it to .install only since it sometimes (who knows why) throws function not implemented when called from .module